# How do I shorten my code in php using different condition?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have problem in using this long sourcecode. Is there any substitute code or condition statement to shorten or minimize the code. I use the if-ElseIf Statement. Thank you!

I actually doing a system regarding on multiple conditions regarding on the specified amount. Ex. If SHARE equal or less than 30,000 their is a specified percentage computed with different months.

```
<div class="span8" align="center">
    <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" width="50%"> 
                <form action="" method="POST">
                <label> *NOTE: Php.36,000.00 - maximum applied loanable amount</label>
                <br/>
                <label>Share Capital:</label>
                <input onBlur="this.value=formatCurrency(this.value)" type="hidden"> 
                <input type="text" name="share" value="0" class="textbox"/><br>
                <label>Term:</label>
                <select name="terms"/>
                        <option value="1">1 Month</option>
                        <option value="2">2 Months</option>
                      </select> <br /> 
                <input type="submit" name="calculate" class="btn btn-success" value="Let's COMPUTE">
                </form></td>

                <td width="50%" align="justify" > 
                    <div class="alert alert-info" align="justify" style="font-size:16px">
                <?php if(isset($_POST['calculate'])) { 
                        $share = $_POST['share']; 
                        $terms = $_POST['terms']; 
                        ?>
                <?php if($share <= "30000"){ ?>
                        <?php if($terms == "1"){ 
                            $interest = $share * .0130;                     
                            $service_fee =  $share * .01;
                            $filling_fee = 30;
                            $cash_on_hand =  $share - ($service_fee + $interest + $filling_fee);
                            $loan_receivable =  $cash_on_hand + $service_fee + $interest + $filling_fee;
                            $debit = $loan_receivable;
                            $credit = $interest + $service_fee + $filling_fee + $cash_on_hand;
                            ?>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Loan Receivable"; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($loan_receivable, 2); ?> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Interest "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($interest, 2); ?> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Service Fee "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($service_fee, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Filling Fee "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($filling_fee, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Cash On Hand "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($cash_on_hand, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold">
                                    <td width="40%" align="right"><?php echo "TOTAL "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($debit, 2); ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($credit, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Applied Loan "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($share, 2); ?> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Term: "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo $terms. " month "; ?> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <?php } elseif($terms == "2"){ 
                            $interest = $share * .0195;                     
                            $service_fee =  $share * .01;
                            $filling_fee = 30;
                            $cash_on_hand =  $share - ($service_fee + $interest + $filling_fee);
                            $loan_receivable =  $cash_on_hand + $service_fee + $interest + $filling_fee;
                            $debit = $loan_receivable;
                            $credit = $interest + $service_fee + $filling_fee + $cash_on_hand;
                            ?>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Loan Receivable"; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($loan_receivable, 2); ?> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Interest "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($interest, 2); ?> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Service Fee "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($service_fee, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Filling Fee "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($filling_fee, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Cash On Hand "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($cash_on_hand, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold">
                                    <td width="40%" align="right"><?php echo "TOTAL "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($debit, 2); ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($credit, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Applied Loan "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($share, 2); ?> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Term: "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo $terms. " months "; ?> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>            


    <!--END OF SHARE 30,000 BELOW -->   <?php } ?>
    <!--START OF SHARE 30,000 ABOVE --> <?php } elseif($share >= "30001"){ ?>
                            <?php if($terms == "1"){ 
                            $interest = $share * .0130;                     
                            $service_fee =  $share * .01;
                            $filling_fee = 30;
                            $cash_on_hand =  $share - ($service_fee + $interest + $filling_fee);
                            $loan_receivable =  $cash_on_hand + $service_fee + $interest + $filling_fee;
                            $debit = $loan_receivable;
                            $credit = $interest + $service_fee + $filling_fee + $cash_on_hand;
                            ?>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Loan Receivable"; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($loan_receivable, 2); ?> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Interest "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($interest, 2); ?> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Service Fee "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($service_fee, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Filling Fee "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($filling_fee, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Cash On Hand "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($cash_on_hand, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold">
                                    <td width="40%" align="right"><?php echo "TOTAL "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($debit, 2); ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($credit, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Applied Loan "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($share, 2); ?> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Term: "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo $terms. " month "; ?> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <?php } elseif($terms == "2"){ 
                            $interest = $share * .0205;                     
                            $service_fee =  $share * .01;
                            $filling_fee = 30;
                            $cash_on_hand =  $share - ($service_fee + $interest + $filling_fee);
                            $loan_receivable =  $cash_on_hand + $service_fee + $interest + $filling_fee;
                            $debit = $loan_receivable;
                            $credit = $interest + $service_fee + $filling_fee + $cash_on_hand;
                            ?>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Loan Receivable"; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($loan_receivable, 2); ?> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Interest "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($interest, 2); ?> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Service Fee "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($service_fee, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Filling Fee "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($filling_fee, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Cash On Hand "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($cash_on_hand, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold">
                                    <td width="40%" align="right"><?php echo "TOTAL "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($debit, 2); ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($credit, 2); ?></td>
                                </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    <td><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Applied Loan "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($share, 2); ?> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Term: "; ?></td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo $terms. " months "; ?> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        <?php } ?>  
                        <?php } ?> 
                    <?php } ?> 
    </div>          </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: store values in variables and print only once.

Comment: How? Can you help me on that code or give me example or can you edit my code using the code you are suggesting. Thanks.

Comment: you r printing html in each if condition. so instead of thst take values in to variables and print only once.

Comment: can you edit my code using the code you are suggesting. thanks

Comment: will give you some demo link, check that.

Comment: ok thanks in advance for demo links.

Comment: see this,http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db96bd8ed8b2673a7a9843d85d335866df126793

Comment: @ElPresidente plz check my answer does it really help ????

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju It only compute $share <= "30000" not $share >= "30001"

Comment: @DarylGill what/who is MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you could do here is create a function (or have this as part of a set of tools saved in a class) that you can make available for reuse via an `include()`. To mix the algorithm into your html will severely limit it's *possible* use elsewhere. It also clutters up your html output when you intersperse it. Creating a function/class->method allows for expandability and porting into other functions/class->methods as well:

```
<?php
// Create a function that can accept parameters
function CalculateItem($share = 0,$terms = 0)
    {
        if($share <= 30000)
            $multiplier =   ($terms == "1")? .0130 : .0195;
        elseif($share >= 30001)
            $multiplier =   ($terms == "1")? .0130 : .0205;

        if(empty($multiplier))
            return;

        $data['share']              =   $share;
        $data['terms']              =   $terms; 
        $data['interest']           =   ($share * $multiplier);                     
        $data['service_fee']        =   ($share * .01);
        $data['filling_fee']        =   30;
        $data['cash_on_hand']       =   $share - ($data['service_fee'] + $data['interest'] + $data['filling_fee']);
        $data['loan_receivable']    =   $data['cash_on_hand'] + $data['service_fee'] + $data['interest'] + $data['filling_fee'];
        $data['debit']              =   $data['loan_receivable'];
        $data['credit']             =   $data['interest'] + $data['service_fee'] + $data['filling_fee'] + $data['cash_on_hand'];

        return $data;
    }

// Get the state of data. Anything but false will trigger the breakout table
$data   =   (isset($_POST['calculate']))? CalculateItem($_POST['share'],$_POST['terms']) : false;
?>

<div class="span8" align="center">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="50%">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <label> *NOTE: Php.36,000.00 - maximum applied loanable amount</label>
                <br/>
                <label>Share Capital:</label>
                <input onBlur="this.value=formatCurrency(this.value)" type="hidden">
                <input type="text" name="share" value="0" class="textbox"/>
                <br>
                <label>Term:</label>
                <select name="terms"/>
                    <option value="1">1 Month</option>
                    <option value="2">2 Months</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="calculate" class="btn btn-success" value="Let's COMPUTE">
            </form></td>
        <td width="50%" align="justify" >
            <div class="alert alert-info" align="justify" style="font-size:16px">
                <?php if($data != false) { ?>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Loan Receivable"; ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($data['loan_receivable'], 2); ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Interest "; ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($data['interest'], 2); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Service Fee "; ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($data['service_fee'], 2); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Filling Fee "; ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($data['filling_fee'], 2); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Cash On Hand "; ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($data['cash_on_hand'], 2); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold">
                        <td width="40%" align="right"><?php echo "TOTAL "; ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($data['debit'], 2); ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($data['credit'], 2); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br/>
                            <br/></td>
                        <td><br/>
                            <br/></td>
                        <td><br/>
                            <br/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Applied Loan "; ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($data['share'], 2); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Term: "; ?></td>
                        <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo $data['terms']. " month "; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: interest in C:\xampp\htdocs\CDC\lchospi.php on line 16, 17, 18, 19

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it. Can you please give me one example. Thanks.

Comment: Refresh my answer, that will have the revised code.

Comment: Great! Make sure to mark the question answered so the question doesn't keep getting traffic thinking it's unsolved.

Comment: thanks @Rasclatt . anyway if i had 10 option the code will be look like this?
if($share <= 30000)
            $multiplier =   ($terms == "1")? .0130 : .0195 : .0260 : .0325 : .0390 : .0455 : .0520 : .0585 : .0650 : .0715;
        elseif($share >= 30001)
            $multiplier =   ($terms == "1")? .0130 : .0205;

        if(empty($multiplier))
            return;

Comment: No, you would do a `switch()` in that case

Comment: As my code stands, for those options the `$multiplier` is based on `$terms`. You have not supplied anymore terms to assign multipliers to. What designates the rest of the values?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:Used previous link and have shortened the code.Please test it properly just did blank coding**

```
 <div class="span8" align="center">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="50%"> 
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <label> *NOTE: Php.36,000.00 - maximum applied loanable amount</label>
                <br/>
                <label>Share Capital:</label>
                <input onBlur="this.value = formatCurrency(this.value)" type="hidden"> 
                <input type="text" name="share" value="0" class="textbox"/><br>
                <label>Term:</label>
                <select name="terms"/>
                <option value="1">1 Month</option>
                <option value="2">2 Months</option>
                </select> <br /> 
                <input type="submit" name="calculate" class="btn btn-success" value="Let's COMPUTE">
            </form></td>

        <td width="50%" align="justify" > 
            <div class="alert alert-info" align="justify" style="font-size:16px">
                <?php
                if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
                    $share = $_POST['share'];
                    $terms = $_POST['terms'];
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($share <= "30000") { ?>
                        <?php
                        if ($terms == "1") {
                            $interest = $share * .0130;
                        } elseif ($terms == "2") {
                            $interest = $share * .0195;
                            if ($terms == "1") {
                                $interest = $share * .0130;
                            } elseif ($terms == "2") {
                                $interest = $share * .0205;
                            }}
```

elseif ($share >= 30001) {
                                if ($terms == "1") {
                                    $interest = $share * .0130;
                                } elseif ($terms == "2") {
                                    $interest = $share * .0205;
                                }
                            }
                                ?>

```
                        ?> 

                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Loan Receivable"; ?></td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($loan_receivable, 2); ?> </td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Interest "; ?></td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($interest, 2); ?> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Service Fee "; ?></td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($service_fee, 2); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Filling Fee "; ?></td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($filling_fee, 2); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Cash On Hand "; ?></td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"> </td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($cash_on_hand, 2); ?></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold">
                                <td width="40%" align="right"><?php echo "TOTAL "; ?></td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($debit, 2); ?></td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($credit, 2); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><br/><br/></td>
                                <td><br/><br/></td>
                                <td><br/><br/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Applied Loan "; ?></td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo number_format($share, 2); ?> </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="40%" align="justify"><?php echo "Term: "; ?></td>
                                <td width="30%" align="right"><?php echo $terms . " month "; ?> </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>



                    <?php } ?> 
            </div>          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: any one can edit and update the code if it is possible to reduce the lines

Comment: It only compute $share <= "30000" not $share >= "30001"